# Finding the optimal number of peaks in curve fitting ( or graph deconvolution), automatically

Tags: python, graph, deconvolution

I am trying to deconvolute graph in a way that captures the most characteristics of the original graph. There are two main issues when I am using the following code:

```
def Gaussian(x, mean, sd):
  Gaussian = []
  for i in range(x.size):
    norm += [1.0/(sd*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(x[i] - mean)**2/(2*sd**2))]
  return np.array(norm)


x_value = np.arange(100)
fun = lambda x: np.exp(-(0.1*x-6)**2+4) + np.exp(-(0.1*x-4.75)**2+2)

y_value1 = fun(x_value) + np.random.normal(0,1,len(x_value))*3

m, dm, sd1, sd2, h1, h2 = [60, 10, 1, 1, 5, 2]
p = [m, dm, sd1, sd2, h1, h2] # Initial guesses for leastsq
y_init = norm(x_value, m, sd1)*h1 + norm(x_value, m + dm, sd2)*h2 # For final comparison plot

def res(p, y, x):
  m, dm, sd1, sd2, h1, h2 = k
  m1 = m
  m2 = m1 + dm
  y_fit = Gaussian(x, m1, sd1) * h1 + Gaussian(x, m2, sd2) * h2
  err = y - y_fit
  return err

ls = least_squares(res, p, args = (y_value1, x_value))
```

The first main issue is that it gives more than one solution. 
The real data shown below is actually very solid. It is kind of obvious that it would have two convoluted graphs. However, in the case where we have more general shape of data, the result starts to extremely vary. I don't think that deconvoluted graphs would explain the inherent characteristics of the original graph.

[image: fitted graphs]

The second issue is that I have to manually set the number of peaks. I want something that determines peak automatically but optimally. Do you guys happen to know any function that does this thing?

Or am I totally missing out something important? I couldn't find the answers that address theses issues.

=============================================================================
EDIT: I imported peakdet from here https://gist.github.com/antiface/7177333
and it works well for the graph shown above. However, another issue came up which was, it doesn't detect the inflection point of curve for such graph like below:

[image]

I am trying to modify the code little bit from peakdet to detect such points as well. Please help!

Comment: You might want to take a look at [scipy.signal-Peak finding](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/signal.html#peak-finding)

Comment: @RickM. I updated it. Scipy tools you recommended helped me to find both local maxes and local mins. However, those would not detect points in the plateau or inflection points

Comment: Hmm interesting, I think you will have to specify that you are looking for multiple peaks

Answer (score 0):

I know, very old post but …

Usually, your detected signal not 100% sharp – you have a so called *point spread function* (PSF), often Gaussian shaped, that 'blurs' the whole curve over the spectrum. This can be taken into account by deconvolution of the raw data (measured spectrum) or, the other way round, by convolution of the convolute graph with the PSF.